# Norm of Polynom

Tags: vector-spaces, definite-integrals, normed-spaces

I'm trying to understand the following equation:

$$\langle p,q\rangle_p=\int_{-1}^1p(x)q(x)dx\\
\text{Basis: }\{p_1,p_2\}\\
p_1:=2x,\quad p_2:=x-1$$

Norm: $$p_1:q_1=\frac{p_1}{\|p_1\|_p}$$
$$\|p_1\|^2_p=\int_{-1}^1(2x)^2dx=\frac{8}{3}$$

Why is this $\frac{8}{3}$?
where does it come from?
How do I calculate the Integral equation?

Comment: What is your mathematical background? Are you familiar with linear algebra (in particular vector spaces, vectors, bases, innerproducts)?  Are you familiar with integration?

Comment: linear algebra yes, but this integration is new to me, at least in that use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of a norm induced from inner product, $\|v\|^2=\langle v,v\rangle$. So in this case $\|p\|^2$ means the integral of $p(x)^2$ from $-1$ to $1$, that is:

$$\int_{-1}^1(2x)^2dx = \int_{-1}^1 4x^2dx = 4\int_{-1}^1x^2dx = 4\left(\frac13x^3)\right)\Big|^1_{-1} = \frac43(1^3-(-1)^3) = \frac43\cdot2 = \frac83$$

Comment: And thus we fully exhausted the set of integrals I can calculate! :-)

Comment: how did you arrive to (1/3)x^3  ? I must be missing something with integrals that I've long forgotten..

Comment: Firstly, let me apologize that my name is not Asaf. The antiderivative/integral of $x^n$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$, because the derivative of $\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$ is $\frac{n+1}{n+1}x^{n} = x^n$.